# Anenu if planning to break the fast

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, fast-days, chazzan-prayer-leader, shacharis-morning-prayer, mincha-afternoon-prayer

I have two related questions about the fast day addition to the Amida "Anenu b'yom tzom taaniteinu":

1. If an individual is fasting when he says mincha, but he plans to break the fast after mincha, should he say Anenu?  I recall being told to do so, but instructions/commentary in some prayer books say it is said at mincha and not Shacharit because the assumption is that one who is still fasting at mincha time will complete the fast.  If the person knows that for him that assumption is false, should he say Aneinu?
2. In shacharit, if enough people are fasting that the chazan would say Aneinu, the community would read the fast day Torah reading, etc, but the expectation is that most of the minyan will break their fast after Shacharit (I expect this would come up in an old age home or the like) does the chazzan still say Aneinu?  If the shaliach tzibur himself plans to break the fast after shacharit, should he say aneinu?  Should they choose a different shaliach tzibur?

Comment: Why are they breaking their fasts? Because they feel like it, or because they’re physically incapable of fasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mechaber and Rema in Shulchan Aruch ([O.C 562:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.562.1?with=all&lang=bi)) say the following:

> ואם דעתו לאכול קודם לכן אינו מתפלל עננו: הגה מיהו נוהגין להתפלל עננו אע"פ שאין משלימין עד צאת הכוכבים וכן דעת מקצת רבוותא (תה"ד סי' קנ"ז) ונראה לי דדוקא ביחיד דאומר עננו בשומע תפלה דבלאו הכי יכול להוסיף כמו שנתבאר לעיל סי' קי"ט אבל שליח ציבור לא יאמר עננו אא"כ משלימין וכן נוהגין
>
> If one plans to eat before that, [the end of the fast] he does not say *anenu*. There are those that say that one should say *anenu* even if he is not going to fast till *tzeit*, but it seems that that's only for an individual, but the Chazan should not say *anenu* unless they will complete the fast.

So the answer to the first part of your question would be: it's a *machloket* between the מחבר and the רמ"א, with the Mechaber holding one should not day it and the Rema holding that if the person fasting a private fast only took upon himself to fast part of the day, then they can say it.

And the answer to the second question is: the chazan does not say anenu in if the congregation is not going to fast till the end.